Scraping pdfs from multiple links
I'm trying to scrape all pds from this link
https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/series/statements-speeches-chair-board-governors-federal-reserve-system-3760
Note that in the link, there are multiple other links, for example
https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/series/statements-speeches-chair-board-governors-federal-reserve-system-3760#452
and within this second link, there are links to documents (in this case, 505 pdfs)
https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/statements-speeches-alan-greenspan-452?browse=1980s
I haven't found a similar question. Any ideas are welcomed!
